# How to create $token for email fortify Laravel?

Tags: passwords, laravel-8, php-8, laravel-fortify

I am overrinding default Fortify password reset to work like welcome email, where user get a link to email for creating new password.

```
 public function store(UserCreateRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
    $token = Str::random(60);
    $user = User::create(array_merge($request->validated(),
      ['password' => bcrypt(Str::random(8))]));
    $user->sendPasswordCreateNotification($token);
    }
```

This way token is not acceptable? What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This code did the correct `$token` for me.

`$token = app(Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::class)->createToken($user);`